# how to create a new google calendar event and fetch its details immediately afterwards?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-calendar-api

My android app creates a new G-calendar event.

The user puts all required fields in the G-calendar Activity and then saves.

I want to save in my mobile DB the  details, after the user saves the event.

i.e. the flow is:

click "new event" ButtonView --> Calendar UI opens --> the user fills fields --> the Calendar UI closes --> the client saves all fileds (related to a event_id) in local sqlite DB

I have tried 2 options.

(Option A) doesn't open the G-Calendar Activity for the user to fill in data

(Option B) opens the  G-Calendar Activity, but I cannot get the event_id for fetching the users filled data.

```
private void exportToGCalendar() {

    //option A
    //Here is an example of inserting an event. This is being performed in the UI thread for simplicity. In practice, inserts and updates should be done in an asynchronous thread to move the action into a background thread. For more information, see AsyncQueryHandler.

    long calID = 3;
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;     
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
    mEventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    // 
    // ... do something with event ID
    //
    //


    //=======

    //option B
    //addCalendarEvent_optionB();
}

private void addCalendarEvent_optionB() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Learn Android");
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home suit home");
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Download Examples");

    // Setting dates
    GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, 02);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                        calDate.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                        calDate.getTimeInMillis());

    // Make it a full day event
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

    // Make it a recurring Event
    intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=11;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH");

    // Making it private and shown as busy
    intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
    intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);

    //     intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How can I achieve my target?